# dc.js TextFilterWidget is not defined

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have installed dc.js (latest version 4.0.0) using npm for my node project and I have a simple table with a text filter component. It says the following error when I try to create new instance of the Textfilter passing the dimension

This is the code used

`new TextFilterWidget('#search').dimension(tableDimension)`

Error Message

> Uncaught ReferenceError: TextFilterWidget is not defined

Comment: Are you including dc.js using ES6 (module by module) or using the `dc.js` bundle? If the latter, the correct syntax is [new dc.TextFilterWidget(...)](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/66f6f31700251afd6b0630e7a9b397296ecf99ed/web-src/examples/text-filter-widget.html#L51). Same as all the charts. The headings on the documentation use the ES6 syntax since they are generated by JSDoc.

Comment: I am not sure of how I am using dc.js i did npm install and imported using require ("dc").

Comment: `TextFilterWidget` is exactly the same as `DataTable` or any of the other charts, so whichever syntax you are using with the others should work for it. The old `dc.textFilterWidget` (with no `new`) should also work.